# Segmentation fault when using strcpy() with pointer to cstring

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, strcpy, c-strings

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    // checked for right number of arguments

    // reading pack name
    char* filename[MAX_STR_LEN];
    strcpy(*filename, argv[1]);  // seg fault here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* filename[MAX_STR_LEN];
```

That declares an array of pointers, and doesn't initialise them to point to anything. Dereferencing them gives undefined behaviour; if you're lucky, a segmentation fault.

You probably meant to declare an array of characters to contain the string:

```
char filename[MAX_STR_LEN];
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
```

Now you just need to make sure the array is large enough; or stop mucking around with low-level C artifacts and use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
char filename[MAX_STR_LEN] // without the * 
strcpy(filename, argv[1]); // without the *
```

better (to avoid stackoverflow ! (lol) ):

```
strncpy( filename, argv[1], sizeof(filename)-1 );
filename[ sizeof(filename)-1 ] = 0;
```

Comment: Preventing stack corruption is a worthy goal, but it doesn't pay to replace it with corrupted data. `strncpy` is hard to use right. Just use `strlen` and give an error message if the array is too small; if it's okay, `strcpy`.

Comment: @PeteBecker I don't like corrupted data and would use strlen + error message if necessary. What may be the problem with my use of strncpy?

Comment: There's no direct way to check whether the copy got truncated, so you end up having to call `strlen` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1) filename is an array of *char.  I'm not sure that's what you want to be doing.  You probably want to have

```
char filename[FOO];
```

2) strcpy expects a (char *, const char *), which you're passing it, but there's no allocated space here for you, see (1)

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
char filename[MAX_STR_LEN];
.
.
strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
```

or better still

```
snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "%s", argv[1]);
```

Comment: @Pete Becker, yes - you are right.  The filename needs to be declared as an array of char.

Comment: beware, snprintf may gives you a string WITHOUT the final 0. Use sizeof(filename)-1

Comment: @manuell - `snprintf` copies up to `n-1` characters, so it's okay to give the exact size of the array. But it won't tell you that the file name got truncated, so it's not really very helpful. Just start with `strlen` to see whether the buffer is big enough. If it is, copy the characters. If it isn't, give an error message and don't copy.

Comment: @manuell, the OpenBSD man page says it will write at most size-1 chars followed by null.

Comment: @ArunTaylor MY BAD! I was reading Microsoft documentation of _snprintf... ==>[]